# Como duplicar select sem option anterior

Tags: jquery, html

O código abaixo, realiza a inserção de um novo `select` ao clicar no botão, porém essa nova lista deverá ser composta apenas com os itens restantes, ou seja, o novo `select` não poderá possuir o `option` selecionado no `select` anterior.

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#addComp').on('click', function(){
     $('.itemComposicao').append($('.itemComposicao').children(":first").html());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="itemComposicao">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="composicao">
        <option value="1">Alumínio</option>
        <option value="2">Cobre</option>
        <option value="3">PVC</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<button type="button" id="addComp">Inserir</button>
```

**Update**:

Obs.: após duplicar este item, como fazer para que o `option` "inserido" não apareça nos `selects` anteriores?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça da seguinte maneira.

> Fonte: [jquery remove/add select options after cloning select list (soEN)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6198303/8353154)

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#addComp').on('click', function(){
      // Guarda primeiro item na variável "original"
      var original = $("#item_composicao:eq(0)");
      // Guarda todos os items na variável "todosSelectes"
      var todosSelects = $("select.composicao");
      // Clona o primeiro item
      var clone = original.clone();
      // Remove os items selecionados anteriormente.
      $('option', clone).filter(function(i) {
        return todosSelects.find('option:selected[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').length;
      }).remove();
      // Verifica a quantidade de opções que tem o último select
      // Se for maior que 1, clona o elemento, caso for igual a 1
      // não faz nada.
      var ultimo = $("select.composicao:last option").size();
      if (ultimo > 1) {
        $('.itemComposicao').append(clone);
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="itemComposicao">
  <div class="form-group" id="item_composicao">
    <select class="composicao">
        <option value="1">Alumínio</option>
        <option value="2">Cobre</option>
        <option value="3">PVC</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<button type="button" id="addComp">Inserir</button>
```

#### Solução

Conforme o comentário, essa foi uma solução que encontrei. Pode ter outras mais simplificada.

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var clone_index = 0;
    $('#addComp').on('click', function(){
      // Guarda primeiro item na variável "original"
      var original = $("#template");
      // Guarda todos os items na variável "todosSelectes"
      var todosSelects = $("select.composicao");
      // Clona o primeiro item
      var clone = original.clone();
      // Exibe na tela
      clone.css({'display': 'inline'});
      // incrementa
      clone_index++;
      // Define uma ID unica
      clone.find("#item_composicao select").attr('id', 'clone_' + clone_index);
      // Verifica se a quantidade de items clonados é menor do que a quantidade
      // de items no #template
      if (clone_index < ($("#template #item_composicao select option").length - 1)) {
        // Verifica se a opção selecionada não é: Seleciona uma Opção
        // Se não for continua, caso contrário exibe mensagem.
        if( clone_index !== 0 && $("#clone_" + (clone_index - 1)).val() === "") {
          // Descrementa.
          clone_index--;
          alert("SELECIONE UMA OPÇÃO");
        } else {
          // Remove o item selecionado anteriormente.
          clone.find("#item_composicao select").on("change", function() {
            todosSelects.find("option[value=" + $(this).val() + "]").remove();
          });
          // Verifica a quantidade de opções que tem o último select
          // Se for maior que 1, clona o elemento, caso for igual a 1
          // não faz nada.
          var ultimo = $("select.composicao:last option").size();
          if (ultimo > 1) {
            $('.itemComposicao').append(clone);
          }
          // Remove os items dos selects menos o item selecionado
          $(".itemComposicao select[id!='clone_"+clone_index+"']").find("option").not(":selected").remove();
        }
      }
    });
});
```

```css
/* OCULTA A DIV #TEMPLATE */
.hidde {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Modal composição -->
 <!-- Modal -->
 <div id="percent-composicao" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
 
  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
   <h4 class="modal-title">Composição</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">

        <!-- COLOQUE ESSE CÓDIGO FORA DA TAG FORM -->
        <div class="row hidde" style="margin-bottom: 35px;" id="template">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6" id="item_composicao">
                <select name="composicao" id="composicao" required="true" class="form-control composicao">
                        <option value="">Selecione uma Opção</option>
                        <option value="1">Alumínio</option>
                        <option value="2">Cobre</option>
                        <option value="3">Madeira</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2" id="percent_comp">
                <input class="form-control" name="percentComp" type="number"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" class="removeComp"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <form method="post" id="formComposicao" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <!-- ESSE CÓDIGO  DENTRO DA TAG FORM -->
            <div class="row itemComposicao"></div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="addComp">Adicionar</button>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Salvar</button>
    </div>
  </div>
 
   </div>
 </div><!--// Modal compo -->
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#percent-composicao">
  Abrir modal de Composição
</button>
```

Comment: Com `size()` o seguinte erro foi apresentado: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).size is not a function`. Contudo, ao utilizar o `length` funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: Wellingthon, poderia dar uma olhada no **update**?

Comment: @luccasrodrigo vou dar uma verificada, então tem que remover dos outros também o que foi selecionado no último certo ?

Comment: Olá Wellingthon, poderiamos continuar esse debate pelo [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65352/como-duplicar-select-sem-option-anterior)?

Answer (score 0):

Duas maneiras:

**Mantendo a opção de inserir:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
   $('#addComp').on('click', function(){
      var valor_excluir = $('.composicao').last().val(); //pego o value selecionado
$('.itemComposicao').append($('.itemComposicao').children(":first").html());
     $('.composicao option[value='+valor_excluir+']').last().remove(); // removo o option com o value selecionado no select anterior
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="itemComposicao">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="composicao">
        <option value="1">Alumínio</option>
        <option value="2">Cobre</option>
        <option value="3">PVC</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<button type="button" id="addComp">Inserir</button>
```

**Esgotar inserir quando todas as opções forem escolhidas:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#addComp').on('click', function(){
  if($('.composicao').length < $('.composicao:eq(0) option').length){
   $('.itemComposicao').append($('.itemComposicao').children(":first").html());
   for(x=0;x<$('.composicao').length-1;x++){
    var valor_excluir = $('.composicao:eq('+x+')').val();
    $('.composicao option[value='+valor_excluir+']').last().remove();
   }
  }else{
   alert("Todos as opções foram usadas!");
  }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="itemComposicao">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="composicao">
        <option value="1">Alumínio</option>
        <option value="2">Cobre</option>
        <option value="3">PVC</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<button type="button" id="addComp">Inserir</button>
```